# Nullish Coalescing on functions

Tags: typescript

I have an interface

```
interface Foo {
   error?: string;
   getError?: (param: any) => string
}
```

Let's say we always want to call the function, but there is the possibility of it being undefined. For base types we could use  `??`:

```
const error = foo.error ?? "No Error";
```

`foo.getError(...)` will throw *... is not a function* which is understandable if there is none :=)

So, is there an equivalent or elegant alternative to the nullish coalescing operator on functions or do I always have to do something like this:

```
const error = foo.getError ? foo.getError(...) ?? "No error" : "No error"
```

Comment: Optional chaining operator works for functions also. So try: `foo.getError?.()`.

Comment: @CRice you are right, thanks! I never thought about that... If you post that as an answer, I can approve it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use optional chaining on your function you could shorten that line to this:

```
const error = foo.getError?.('...') ?? "No error"
```